# Wince: Setting values to hive gets reset after reboot?

Tags: hive, registry, windows-ce, persistent-storage

I have made a program that cleans the hive when a button is pressed on boot. To test this feature, I needed a program that sets and reads to the hive.

I found that if I create a new key or set a value to a pre-existing persistent key, it all gets reset after reboot.

I was wondering if there is a flag that still needs to set in order to store persistent values.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but are you running your own, custom OS image, and if so, have you enabled the hive and verified that it works? And if using an off-the-shelf device/image, is that device configured to support a registry hive?

Answer (score 0):

You should call RegFlushKey to ensure that data is written in the hive file and you should also check that the hive files are stored on some permanent memory.

Comment: Yes, I am already calling that function. but it does not seem to work.

Comment: do you have system.hv and user.hv files somewhere in your filesystem? You should check that they are on a folder that is on a permanent mass-storage device, otherwise their contents will be wiped on reboot.

Comment: Yes, I have user.hv and system.hv on the nand storage.

Comment: Can you check if their datetime changes when you flush the registry?
If hive is in NAND flash values should be permanent.
Do you have some kind of write cache on that nand?

Comment: Date and time seem to never change. In regards to write cache, I am not sure. Just out of curiosity, is there a possibility that this problem is related to  "Registry Key Security and Access Rights" or PRJ_ENABLE_FSREGHIVE flag?